# Why is this lambda expression not working for defining this comparator?

Tags: java, comparator, priority-queue, heap

I want to create a min-heap where the elements are pairs of integers and I want the heap to compare the first number in the pair. I am defining it like so:

```
PriorityQueue<List<Integer>> heap = new PriorityQueue((a, b) -> a.get(0) - b.get(0));
```

However, this causes these errors:

```
ERROR!
javac /tmp/1YraTeGijp/HelloWorld.java
/tmp/1YraTeGijp/HelloWorld.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
PriorityQueue<List<Integer>> heap = new PriorityQueue((a, b) -> a.get(0) - b.get(0));
                                                                         ^
  symbol:   method get(int)
  location: variable a of type Object
/tmp/1YraTeGijp/HelloWorld.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        PriorityQueue<List<Integer>> heap = new PriorityQueue((a, b) -> a.get(0) - b.get(0));
^
  symbol:   method get(int)
  location: variable b of type Object
Note: /tmp/1YraTeGijp/HelloWorld.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I tried using types when defining the a and b parameters but that also raised errors. Whats the fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an IDE, you should see the following warning :

> PriorityQueue is a raw type. References to generic type PriorityQueue should be parameterized

You are missing `<List<Integer>>` or simply `<>` after `new PriorityQueue` :

```java
PriorityQueue<List<Integer>> heap = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> a.get(0) - b.get(0));
```

Comment: Addendum: using minus as comparator function is broken, as it can overflow. In this example, `Comparator.comparingInt(list -> list.get(0))` should be used. If you really have to write the comparison function manually, use `Integer.compare(…, …)`

Comment: @Holger Yes. Absolutely. [Subtraction is not the same as comparison](https://blog.mischel.com/2023/02/05/how-not-to-compare-integers/)